# How do I use "each" on an Openstruct object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `OpenStruct` hash like this:

```
#<OpenStruct object1={
                       "param1"=>"2", 
                       "param2"=>"1"
                     }, 
             object2={
                       "param1"=>"2", 
                       "param2"=>"1"
                     }, 
             object3={
                       "param1"=>"2", 
                       "param2"=>"1"
                     }...
```

How can I use `each` on this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

OpenStruct has a method called [marshal_dump](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-marshal_dump) that returns the underlying hash structure:

```
your_open_struct.marshal_dump.each{ |k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v}" }
```

If you are using Ruby 2.0, you can use also [to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-to_h) like so:

```
your_open_struct.to_h.each{ |k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v}" }
```

Unlike `marshal_dump`, which returns the actual hash structure, `to_h` returns a hash with all the keys converted to symbols for easier access.